# Multer working locally but not in production

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, multer

so i have been several hours on this and i now have no idea on what to do

I want to note that this works in development but it is not working in production, so it works locally but it isnt working on the server

So I have this in my `index.js`

```
server.post('/something', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('start')
  console.log(req.body, res.body)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

That snippet of code, works, i receive the request, just that no body is in there cause it is a multipart form data, as soon as i add multer in hangs and nginx says connection timed out

```
server.post('/something', upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log('start')
  console.log(req.body, res.body)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

So i have tried to add a Timeout there but it isn't working the current Multer config is the following one

```
const upload = multer()
```

If it has multer and i send a Postman request with just a simple raw text it says okay if i use the form-data in Postman it will hang again

I have tried adding a `dest` to the multer, still not working
Also tried to add time out to the node server and also have tried to remove the rate limiter, also tried to add the following to nginx

```
   proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300;
```

Edit: Added the full nginx conf and err

```
worker_processes auto;
#Check the concnections
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 15m;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    upstream ip{
        least_conn;
        server app:4000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080; # ssl;
        server_name ip;
        # ssl on;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ip/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
    }
}
```

```
*3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ip, server: ip, request: "POST /something HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.0.0.4:4000/something", host: "ip:8080"
```

Comment: Check NGINX logfiles for clues. Also, what's the full proxy setup of NGINX?

Comment: @robertklep added the nginx conf and the err to the post

Comment: "Connection refused". So NGINX cannot connect to your app. This sounds like a configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: Yep that error was with some try i don't remember which one but the problem is that it works with multer and if i don't send the form data but it doesn't iif i send the request with the formdata

Comment: Is your app server crashing?

Comment: nop, no error on the node server

Comment: Although I wouldn't expect Multer to be influenced by this, you may want to take a look at [configuring Express to work behind a proxy server](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

Comment: Are you using docker? Why else would you use "app" as upstream in nginx?

Comment: yes we are using docker

Comment: Seems like a network related issue in docker. Are the container share the same network? Do you use docker-compose? If so, share your yaml file.